# Error in Routes.rb config syntax error in line 11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through the rubyonrails tutorial by Michael hartl and I was only updating the routes.rb config as required at end of chapter 1 in order to add a application#goodbye.

However, now even my application#hello shows a syntax error in line 11 , eventhough i didn't change that line at all.

Any ideas on why ?

Here is a pic of the file and the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWkA.png)

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: single quote line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 7, opens a string with `'`. It reports the error on that line because a `'` closes the string and the rest becomes error.

Comment: O yah ! Duh! Thank you so much . The life of a newbie !

Comment: Happy to help, not sure why are you getting down votes. It will help if instead of a link to an image, you post the relevant parts on your `routes.rb` file in the question text instead.

Comment: So don't post an image and instead post only the description of the erroneous text ?

Comment: If an image helps, yes, post it. But in this case, having the text provides all the context for the question within the question, without needing to leave the page.

Comment: Got it . Thanks again . Will do!